# How to load DLL file from Jscript file?

Tags: dll, jscript

So I'm writing a standalone `JScript` file to be executed by `Windows Script Host` (this file is not going to be used as a web application).

My goal is to load a dll file. Just like using [LoadLibrary function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in a `C++` application.

I tried researching the subject but I didn't come up with anything useful. I'm so lost I don't have any piece of code to share. I understand using `ActiveXObject` may come to my rescue. if so, any idea how to use it?

#### Update:

If we all agree that loading is impossible, I'll settle for validity check. Meaning, don't try to load but check if it is loaded and functional.

Comment: I don't understand why you think such a thing is possible if your DLL is NOT an ActiveX.

Comment: @manuell I didn't suggest it's possible. I Hope it is (in some way). I'll accept any convincing answer saying it is *not* possible.

Comment: Are you using nodejs or what?

Comment: Just using plian `JScript` that is run using `Windows Script Host`. [JScript Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yek4tbz0(v=vs.84).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export a specific function for this purpose.
Then, from your JScript, execute **rundll32.exe** and check that the function ran as expected.

Answer (score 3):

You might also give [Gilles Laurent's DynaWrap](http://glsft.free.fr/index.php?option=content&task=view&id=47) 
ocx a chance.

This kind of dll needs to be registered on the target system like `regsvr32 /s DynaWrap.dll`.

It is restricted to 32-bit DLLs, and this might be inconvenient for you to use, but it works on a 64bit Windows. You can't access function exported by ordinal number and you can't directly handle 64bit or greater values/pointers.

Here's a sample to call `MessageBoxA` from JScript:

```js
var oDynaWrap = new ActiveXObject( "DynamicWrapper" )

// to call MessageBoxA(), first register the API function
oDynaWrap.Register( "USER32.DLL", "MessageBoxA", "I=HsSu", "f=s", "R=l" )

// now call the function
oDynaWrap.MessageBoxA( null, "MessageBoxA()", "A messagebox from JScript...", 3 )
```

And here from VBScript:

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim oDynaWrap
Set oDynaWrap = CreateObject( "DynamicWrapper" )

' to call MessageBoxA(), first register the API function
UserWrap.Register "USER32.DLL", "MessageBoxA", "I=HsSu", "f=s", "R=l"

' now call the function
UserWrap.MessageBoxA Null, "MessageBoxA()", "A messagebox from VBScript...", 3
```

To use a function you need to "register" the exported function of your DLL. 
To do this you need to call the register method with a first parameter containing a string object to the complete path of the DLL, a second parameter for the exported name of the function to use, and following three paremeters describing the functions declartion in a somehow obscure syntax.

`i=` describes the number and data type of the functions parameters.

`f=` describes the type of call: `_stdcall` or `_cdecl`. Default to `_stdcall`.

`r=` describes the return values data type.

The supported data types are:

```
Code  Variant      Description

a     VT_DISPATCH  IDispatch*
b     VT_BOOL      BOOL
c     VT_I4        unsigned char
d     VT_R8        8 byte real
f     VT_R4        4 byte real
h     VT_I4        HANDLE
k     VT_UNKNOWN   IUnknown*
l     VT_I4        LONG
p     VT_PTR       pointer
r     VT_LPSTR     string by reference
s     VT_LPSTR     string
t     VT_I2        SHORT
u     VT_UINT      UINT
w     VT_LPWSTR    wide string
```

Thus the `Register` method call used in the examples describes `MessageBoxA` like this:

```winapi
_stdcall LONG MessageBoxA( HANDLE, LPSTR, LPSTR, UINT );
```

For a explanation of MessageBoxA look at the docs on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Please read the *DynaWrap* docs for more sophisticated examples... But you might need Google translate, 'cos they are written in french ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use a dll as ActiveXObject, it needs to be [registered as COM object](http://ss64.com/nt/regsvr32.html). There are some restrictions on this but if you have a code for this dll, it is certainly doable.

When you register your dll as COM object, it is assigned a name. You use this name to create an object. This [example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7sw4ddf8(v=vs.94).aspx) uses excel since it is already registered if you installed office.

```
var ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var ExcelSheet = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Sheet");
// Make Excel visible through the Application object.
ExcelSheet.Application.Visible = true;
// Place some text in the first cell of the sheet.
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = "This is column A, row 1";
// Save the sheet.
ExcelSheet.SaveAs("C:\\TEST.XLS");
// Close Excel with the Quit method on the Application object.
ExcelSheet.Application.Quit();
```

Apart from restriction of registering dll, using dll is no different from using it as c++ or c# dll. Note that, C# (or other .NET dlls) should be [ComVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3fd4a20.aspx) to be used from javascript this way.

EDIT: The only other way of using C/C++ dll from javascript is [swig](http://www.swig.org/) interfaces. I have not used it, therefore I can only point you in that direction.

> SWIG is a software development tool that connects programs written in
>   C and C++ with a variety of high-level programming languages. SWIG is
>   used with different types of target languages including common
>   scripting languages such as Javascript, Perl, PHP, Python, Tcl and
>   Ruby.

Comment: 10x for the help. However this answer does not help me solve my issue in any way. I'm well aware on how to work with `ActiveXObject` so the example doesn't really help me. If you have a piece of JScript code that load DLL, please share.